# Solving $2 + \frac 1{\cos^2 x} + \frac 5{\cos x} = 0$

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics

Simple but confusing trig question:

> $$2 + \frac 1{\cos^2 x} + \frac 5{\cos x} = 0$$

I could not find anything in my textbook similar to this....

Comment: Perhaps the first thing would be to notice that this can be written as a quadratic in $\sec x=\dfrac 1{\cos x}$.  After attempting this, it would be a good idea to note where $\cos x=0$ so that any possible division-by-zero issues can be taken care of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: by multiplying both sides by $\cos^2 x$, this is the same equation as
$$
2\cos^2x + 1 + 5\cos x = 0,
$$
which is a quadratic equation in $\cos x$.

Comment: excluding that $\cos x$ might be null

Answer (score 0):

$2y^2+ 5y+ 1= 0$

By the quadratic formula

$y=\dfrac{-5\pm \sqrt{25-8}}{4}$

Comment: You have to check whether each root for $y$ makes a real root for $x$.  Cosines of real numbers must not have absolute values greater than 1.